# Есть ли в windows или Java стандартные иконки работы с файлами и печати?

Tags: java, windows, изображения, swing, иконки

Пишу учебную программу на Java. Нужны иконки "Добавить", "удалить" и "печать".

Программа разрабатывается на Windows 10, ее будут запускать на 7 и XP. Дизайн кнопок и всех компонентов подстроится автоматически, а вот иконки — нет, поэтому качать их из интернета не хочется.

Хранятся ли где-то в ОС такие стандартные иконки, чтобы можно было один раз прописать путь к ним, и получать разный дизайн иконок на разных версиях системы? Или, возможно, это предусмотрено в Java?

Comment: JavaFX используете?

Comment: @biggiemot нет, только swing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Иконки можно найти в %%\Windows\System32\imageres.dll

Но тут есть несколько проблем(нюансов):

1) Они хранятся в dll файле, и следовательно потребуются дополнительные библиотеки чтобы их оттуда достать.

2) Состав иконок может не совпадать. Например в 10тке их больше.

3) Путь до imageres.dll нельзя считать абсолютным и вероятно эту самую библиотеку потребуется находить.

С учетом вышеперечисленного настоятельно рекомендую все таки притащить свои и воткнуть их в сборку. С учетом того что Java это про мультиплатформенность - то это будет  еще и архитектурно правильно.